# Why does this happen ? (reasks user) C++

Tags: c++

Hello so I'm trying to make a game (Pokémon based) using C++ and i'm getting weird results.
Basically you input your name and it says are you called that . If yes , you get asked what type you prefer. However if you input N then Y , for some reason it asks the user more than once what type they prefer.

My code :

Animals.cpp (i only say this one because it's the place where the program asks the user) :

```
// Animals.cpp : This file contains the 'main' function. Program execution begins and ends there.
//
void startgame();
void askname();
void asktype();
void giveGrassStarter();
void giveWaterStarter();
void giveFireStarter();
#include <iostream>
#include "plantee.h"
// #include "visualanimal.h"
#include <cstring>
using namespace std;
string name;
char type;
char answer;
bool success;

int main()
{
    using namespace Animals;
    startgame();
    return 0;
}
void startgame() {
    askname();
    cout << "Alright then. You're " << name << " , right?" << "(Y/N)";
    cin >> answer;
    switch (answer) {
        case 'N':
            startgame();
    }
    asktype();
}
void askname() {
    cout << "Welcome. Your Journey In the World Of Animals Starts here . Please input your name";
    cin >> name;
}
void asktype() {
    cout << "Welcome " << name << " . What type do you prefer? Water ? Grass? Fire? (W/G/F)";
    cin >> type;
    switch (type) {
    case 'G':
        giveGrassStarter();
        break;
    case 'W':
        giveWaterStarter();
        break;
    case 'F':
        giveFireStarter();
        break;
    default:
        cout << "Input invalid . (G for Grass , W for Water , F for Fire)";
        asktype();
    }
}

void giveGrassStarter()
{
    cout << "So you chose Plantee , the grass-type starter. Good choice";
    Plantee starter;
}

void giveWaterStarter()
{
    cout << "So you chose Wateree , the water-type starter. Good choice";
}

void giveFireStarter()
{
    cout << "So you chose Flamee , the fire-type starter. Good choice";
}
```

Anybody knows what i'm doing wrong?

Comment: i have other used files but they don't impact it , if you request the other code i'll add it

Comment: Can you share the exact sequence of inputs from the start? That might help.

Comment: Unrelated to your question, but whomever taught you programming haven't done a good job. Don't use global variables. Don't do recursion (function calling itself) for simple loops. Always expect the unexpected (especially when it comes to use input) so always have input validation and checks for input you don't expect. Don't use `switch` for simple "yes"/"no" choices. Don't include `<cstring>` unless you need to work with C-style null-terminated strings and related C functions.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude thx but i'm teaching myself

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because you are using recurrence for validation. It's going to give you hard time if you continue doing that.

Let's examine your call stack (number near function name is recursion depth):

1. `main()` calls `startGame1`
2. `startGame1` asks for input, you enter `N`, `startGame2` is called.
3. `startGame2` calls `askType`
4. `askType` does its things and returns.
5. `startGame2` returns
6. `startGame1` picks up after `switch` and the next instruction is to call `askType`
7. `askType` does its things (again).

You can use a while loop instead:

```
void startgame() {
    char answer = 'N';
    while (answer == 'N') {
        askname();
        cout << "Alright then. You're " << name << " , right?" << "(Y/N)";
        cin >> answer;
    }
    asktype();
}
```

Also, try to avoid global variables. They are common troublemakers. You only need `answer` in one function, declare it there. Same for `type`.